# How to avoid duplicate in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, asp.net-core

Here my design database, I working on E-commerce project
[image]

So when the admin create a new product its have new Id and the user have to select the color and size for the product. The problem is when create a new product (I set Product's Id is Identity Increment) I enter the same data as the same name, same size and color, etc. just like the same product I imported earlier [image: example] Thats mean the product i just created and the previous product are different but in fact is just one product. Is cause a dupplicate problem . Is there any solutions about this problem?

Is my design wrong?[image] I want when the user create like the product but with same attributes its will be the error and not allowed to save (btw I code in ASP net Core)

I solved this problem by this [image]

To avoid duplicated data we need to break down more table and set the productCode as unique value

Comment: When you were informed *"A question with that title [already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47376529/design-database); please be more specific."* That wasn't a reason to typo "design". The key part was **please be more specific**. Meaningful title are *important*.

Comment: You say that, @NghĩaNghĩa, but I *hate* working with databases where every ID column is called `id` ([so]'s database being one of them). It honestly makes things much cleaner and clear when the ID column *specifies* what type of ID is it.

Comment: decide what makes a product unique and create a unique index on those columns to stop duplicates.

Comment: I think you'll get more luck to have product and separate attribute, prices and stockkeeping tables. Also, with your design, if you have a T-shirt product, how do you separate them? Usually there should be some sort of article number which is not auto-generated. ALso, to be honest, database design is not a proper stackO topic.

Comment: My suggestion is you change tags of this question to c# ef-core etc. Your issue is not a db-issue, it is a code issue

Comment: Okay I get it i will change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to block duplicates (in regards to a select number of columns) you have a few different ways to do it.

The basic ones would be:

1. UNIQUE CONSTRAINT.

Will block any attempts to add an existing combination of the columns.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE ADD CONSTRAINT unique_combo UNIQUE (column1, column2, ...)
```

2. Hide the INSERT behind a STORED PROCEDURE that checks for existing combination of the columns.

Now design wise I would strongly suggest to rework your database design and think about things like if amount makes sence on a product level if you can have multiple sizes...

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

Don't use "Name" or "Id" as column names. Instead use product_name, color_name, size_name, product_id, color_id, size_id.

Remove amount from the product table. Create an new inventory table with inventory_id, product_fk, amount, container_type, container_location, insert_date, expiry_date, stocker_id.

Each table should have an auto-incrementing primary key that is hidden from the users. product_pk, inventory_pk, color_pk, size_pk.

validation of inserts and edits should be handled via your application and only via database constraints as a final safety net. The table designs and relationships should not be used to prevent duplicates because you may one day have an example were a duplicate is needed.

There are many database design best practices you should be aware of before starting a project. See https://www.sisense.com/blog/better-sql-schema/